# WordPress how to redirect Private Custom Post Types

Tags: wordpress, redirect, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

We have a WordPress website with a custom theme and we're using CPTs (Custom Post Types).

For some reason/s, when we set the CPT Visibility to Private, the pages are still available publicly but it's a completely empty document; no `head` data, no `body` data other than a `string(n) "post_title"` for example: `string(9) "ade184065"`.

You can find a live example here:

> https://www.gozoprime.com/gozo-properties/ade184065/

As you can see, it's a property listing website, and when a property is sold we set it as private, as we would still like to keep the data.

I really did my best to try and find what could be causing this, but after hours on-end, I'm not getting anywhere and there's nothing related online - so my thought is that we have a clash with our own custom code?

Disabling all plugins did not solve the issue either.

Has anyone encountered this problem before perhaps?

Note: I also tried to detect if post is private and manually redirect, but whatever happens is happening before the actual property page code is ran. So placing this code in content-single-cpt-name.php doesn't work:

```
// Check post status: Public | Private -> Redirect accordingly
if ( get_post_status ( get_the_ID() ) == 'private' ) { ...
```

Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could solve this issue. Since, you haven't provided details about your cpt, i'd say, try to redirect the user if a post has private status. Again there are other ways to do it but you didn't give us more details on how you've setup your cpt.

In the following code, i'm using `template_redirect` action hook and `wp_safe_redirect` to redirect the user to the `home_url`. Feel free to change the `home_url` to whatever url you need to redirect the user to!

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'your_theme_private_posts_redirect');

function your_theme_private_posts_redirect()
{
    if (is_single() && 'private' == get_post_status(get_the_ID())) {
        wp_safe_redirect(home_url());
        exit();
    }
}
```

The code goes to the `functions.php` file of your active theme. Just tested it and it works fine!

---

**UPDATE**

Since you're using a custom theme, there might be other redirects that would prevent this functionality from executing properly. Therefore, you could add a priority, let's say `99`, to the code i provided you with, and hopefully it'll solve the issue, like so:

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'your_theme_private_posts_redirect', 99);

function your_theme_private_posts_redirect()
{
    if (is_single() && 'private' == get_post_status(get_the_ID())) {
        wp_safe_redirect(home_url());
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The hook template_redirect is not working and I still see the empty page with that string - which makes me think that whatever happens if happening before this hook. Do you know perhaps about another hook prior to this that we can still check for post status private? We are using the manual method of CPTs listed here: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/

Comment: Yesterday right before i sent my answer, i created several "dummy posts" for the regular wordpress blog post and set the status to `private` for a few of them. Then tested my answer and it worked seamlessly fine!. So the problem is on your end. Now, it's hard to debug your code if you don't provide me with more details. If you want me or other people to help you then please edit your question and include your cpt code/structure clearly. I'll take a look if i get a chance but be aware that the code i gave you is working fine and using the right hook because i tested it before sending it to you.

Comment: Crazy, I found out that there was another template_redirect hook which was being called prior to this one. So you really helped figure it out by placing me in the right direction, I don't think I would have found this otherwise - thank you. Can you please update your answer with a notice that there might also be the chance that another template_redirect hook is already present - which could be the reason why private posts do not behave properly (it was our case in the end). I'll accept it as a valid answer :) Thanks again!

Comment: Done! Just updated my answer. Good job tracking down the bug in your custom theme.